# how to deploy a model trained on TF2 Keras on Movidius Myriad 2 (NCSDK 2.05.00.02)

Tags: keras, intel, openvino, movidius, ncsdk

I try to optimize my model using 'MvNCCompile' but it doesn't accept my frozen TF2 graph.
'Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.'.

Can I somehow convert my TF2 (keras) model to TF1 graph format so it can be used? Or is there another way to get the TF2 Keras model to be accepted by the Intel optimisation tool?

Answer (score 0):

Hm. MvNCCompile is a deprecated tool to work with NCS2. I suggest you to try the latest version of OpenVINO: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/